# Mirror transform applying from object centre point

Tags: modeling, transforms, mirror, mirror-modifier

So I'm creating a character model where I've been utilising the mirror modifier to project the parts of the body from one side onto the other successfully, however, I'm having issue with the hand. When mirrored it mirrors over itself instead of across to the other side of the model. In addition to this I have also found that when trying to apply transforms the hand is moved and rotated.
Any help on this would be very much appreciate, its got me pretty stuck, and I'd like to avoid having to remodel an entire hand again.
[image: This is where the hand is supposed to be before mirroring]

[image: This is the hand when I add the mirror modifier]

[image: And this is the hand once I apply all transforms]

Comment: Apply the rotation of the hand to make sure that its orientation is aligned with the global orientation, which is more convenient, and also keep in mind that the Mirror, by default, will use the object's origin as mirror center, so if you want the hand to be mirrored on the other side you can move the origin or choose a mirror object like an empty or another object

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I set the origin to the 3d cursor at the center, however when I mirror it doesn't go to the correct place, its going its close-ish but not right. As for Applying rotation, this literally makes it rotate by like 20 degrees each time I do it, even subsequently.

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thrown it up, hope you have some luck with it

Comment: you need to share the link it will give you (i.e. the URL it will generate)

Comment: Ah sorry, I haven't used this before https://pasteall.org/blend/e353b0d3efaf44f2a91b5a5852d17ff8

Comment: it's ok, please see my answer, you've changed the Delta Transform values

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the *Delta Transform* values, it moves and rotate your object, bring them back to the default values:

[image]

Comment: Great, that did the trick, thanks allot for the time and help. I'd vote up your answer if I had to rep to do so